# Unity Video Player: Resolution exceeds the Microsoft Media Foundation decoder limit

Tags: unity, windows, video

I'm using **Unity**'s **Video Player** component to play a short intro video before the main menu.

The problem is that its resolution is **2560x1440**, and on **Windows 7 or earlier operating systems** it says:

```
Context: Setting media type for first video stream
Error details: The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object.
Track types:
   Audio Track, type: %10%16
   Video Track [2560 x 1440], type: H264
      Resolution exceeds the Microsoft Media Foundation  decoder limit of 1920 x 1088 on Windows 7 and below.
```

**Is there a way to check whether it's supported or not?** Because then I could change the played video to a lower resolution version. And if that's not supported as well, I would just skip the intro all-together.

I would be happy with other solutions as well.

**EDIT:** What I'm trying now is:

- subscribing to errorReceived,
- and if currently it's the 1440p version, I switch back to the 1080p version and play it.
- If errorReceived is fired again (so the current version is 1080p), I just skip the whole intro phase.

  ```
   videoPlayer.errorReceived += OnErrorReceived;

   ...

   private void OnErrorReceived(VideoPlayer videoPlayer, string message)
   {
       if (videoPlayer.clip == Intro1440p)
       {
           OnIntroFinished(videoPlayer);
           videoPlayer.clip = Intro1080p;
           videoPlayer.Play();
       }
       else
       {
           OnIntroFinished(videoPlayer);
       }
   }
  ```

Now the **intro is skipped if no suitable format is found**, which is good, but for some reason even the **1080p version is unsupported**:

```
Context: Setting media type for first video stream
Error details: The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object.
Track types:
   Audio Track, type: %10%16
   Video Track [1920 x 1080], type: H264
```

I've now added an 1080p **wmv** version, after all that's a Windows format, it must be supported by Windows 7.

But it's still unsupported:

```
Context: Setting media type for first video stream
Error details: The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object.
Track types:
   Audio Track, type: a%01
   Video Track [1440 x 1080], type: WMV3
```

Comment: Want to share your current solution as an Answer? You can always edit/delete the answer later if you find it's not suitable.

Comment: Sadly no. I tried improving it further, but it's still not good. At least now it's skipped if the video isn't supported, but I still can't figure out the supported format for Windows 7.